# jsreport Simple Report - No output

Tags: node.js, jsreport

I'm trying to output my first simple report so I can start working with `jsreport`. This is the code I have but it's not outputting anything.

It runs on port `8080`, no error's. It just sits there when I go to the localhost url.

```
var http = require('http');

function handleRequest ( request, response ) {
    require('jsreport').render('<h1>Hello world</h1>').then(function ( out ) {
        out.result.pipe(resp);
    });
}

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

server.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", 8080);
});
```

I'm probably not serving the content correctly, but their documentation is extremely lacking for implementation into your own app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsreport.render` returns a [promise](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and you should properly handle its failures

```
require('jsreport').render('<h1>Hello world</h1>').then(function ( out ) {
  out.result.pipe(resp);
}).catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  response.end(e.message);
});
```

Applying it on your code I get an error which points out you have a typo in `out.result.pipe(resp);`. It should be `out.result.pipe(response);`